# Godot : how can i add a script to autoload only in script?

Tags: autoload, godot, gdscript

Im asking how i can add a script to autoload in godot with only lines of code in one file -> to run functions and get vars from this file to a 2. file.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question. It is not too late edit your question and make it more useful for others. :)

Answer (score 5):

### Adding a script only autoload form the editor

If you go to the Project menu -> Project Settings… -> Autoload tab, on the top you will see a field that says "path", and an button with the icon of a folder. There you can select a file to add as autoload. It can be a scene or it can be a script. Once you have chosen the file, you give it a name (Godot will generate a name based on the name of the file, you can change it) and then click "Add".

When the file you selected is a script, Godot will create a `Node` for it of the Type the script extends.

You will be able to access the `Node` from any script of any scene using the name given to the auto-load.

---

Thus, if you add an script to autolaod, for example:

```
extends Node

var name:String
```

With the name - for example - "Data", you should be able to acess it form from any script attached to a `Node` in any scene. For example, like this:

```
print(Data.name)
```

---

### Adding an autoload from code

If you are writing a plugin, you might want to add an autoload from code. To do this you can use the method `add_autoload_singleton` of the `EditorPlugin` class (if you are writing an plugin, you have one of those), like this:

```
add_autoload_singleton(name, path)
```

And to remove it you can use the `remove_autoload_singleton` method:

```
remove_autoload_singleton(name)
```

These are equivalent to adding and removing the autoload from the editor UI. *I remind you that editor plugins run in the editor.*

---

By the way, the autoloads are `Node`s configured to be added in the scene tree, but not under the current scene. We can do that in runtime directly too, however we would lack the convenience of having the name available everywhere. This is how we would do it:

```
get_tree().root.add_child(node)
```

If you are trying to add a scene, you can do this:

```
var packed_scene:PackedScene = load(path) # or preload
get_tree().root.add_child(packed_scene.instance())
```

And if you are trying to add a script, you can do this:

```
var script:Script = load(path) # or preload
get_tree().root.add_child(script.new())
```

Since we are adding these `Node`s to `get_tree().root` and not to `get_tree().current_scene` when Godot changes `current_scene` they will not be affected.

*Thus, the reason why we need a script attached to `Node` in the scene tree to access the autoload is because they autoload is a `Node` in the scene tree, and thus we need access to the scene tree to access the autoload.*

---

### Alternatives

We have two alternatives to autoloads. They are not exactly the same, but they have some overlap in functionality. To avoid making this answer any longer, I'll just mention them:

- a named class with static method
- custom resources (search for resource based communication).

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with my problem. I m sorry that I forgot to write more specifical about my question.
Have a good day! :D